# Using flexbox, safe to use? Use it everywhere, anytime?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I have a question regarding the use of CSS flexbox. Flexbox feels like a game changer, it is so much more usable and quicker then using floats, positioning or javascript.

Cross-browser issues seem relative doable although I don't see flexbox used very often in the wild. I've seen it been released a couple years ago but because of browser issues never trusted it enough to use it in big projects.

Did anybody build a big, cross-browser project with it? Any tips or definitive guides to share?

Comment: The whole story is here: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex. Nowadays everyone is using it. E.g Bootstrap & Foundation are making Flex Versions. Checkout Bulma.io for a full flexbox based framework. I think the only concern of big companies is SafarIE :)

Comment: yes, I know, but stuff like "IE 11 requires a unit to be added to the third argument, the flex-basis property" isn't clear to me.

Comment: For every flex related confusion i always go to : http://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/adLPwv

Comment: You shoud just add a % after the third unit in the flex-basis shorthand. i.e. `flex: 1 1 0%` otherwise IE will ignore the property.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 10):

It really depends on how far back you want to support Internet Explorer users. I would check out caniuse.com's compatibility chart for flexbox. It includes all the browsers that allow for flexbox in addition to the bugs that people encounter (particularly with IE10 and 11).
http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Flexbox needs a minimum of IE10, but according to caniuse.com, the overall browser usage of IE8 + IE9 less than 1%, making it extremely low in terms of overall browser usage. I would say the only reason not to use flexbox is that if a certain percentage of your users are going to be governments/corporations, as they generally tend to be late with computer upgrades (increased likelihood of IE8 and 9 browsers).

Comment: I wouldn't bother supporting ie 8 - 10 anymore, microsoft don't and the only way we can get users to upgrade is to give them a bad experience

Comment: As horrible as that sounds, I agree. They are likely the type of people that say, "if it ain't broke, don't fix it." So let's give them a reason to update their browsers!